# ApiTaster gem don't recognize any routes in Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, routes

I have Rails 3.2 application and 'api_taster' gem installed. I have some routes defined and described at ApiTaster.routes do ... end block. But, when I opens /api_taster URL I see message Missing definitions detected and list that include ALL my routes.

I have no ideas WHAT is broken and HOW can I debug and fix it.

This application was in working state two days ago. So, I'm sure that all setting are correct. Routes descripted at separate files, store at 'lib/api_tasters/v1' folder. They are loaded with initializer with next code:

```
ApiTaster.route_path = Rails.root.join('lib', 'api_tasters', 'v1')
```

I think that it was some code changed somewhere in project, but I can't understand how I can find what is wrong and how to debug it.